# Absolute addressing fields in a record type

Tags: delphi, record, discriminated-union

I am attempting to interface with an embedded system that transmits and receives data with a fairly simple format but has strict sizing requirements.

In C, you would use a union type to expose some variable data with potentially different types located at the same spot in memory. Add a variable of this union type to a struct, and then you can (carefully) refer to that struct field with various names and types:

*for simplicity, please ignore byte alignment and packing*

```c
typedef enum { F1_V1, F1_V2, F1_V3 } FLAG_1_T;
typedef enum { F2_V1, F2_V1        } FLAG_2_T;

typedef union
{
  FLAG_1_T flag_1;
  FLAG_2_T flag_2;
}
FLAG_T;

typedef struct
{
  BYTE_T  id;
  INT32_T value;
  FLAG_T  flag;
}
DATA_ITEM_T;
```

So now I can interpret the `flag` field as either `FLAG_1_T` or `FLAG_2_T`.

I would like to use this same sort of approach in Delphi 2010. I've tried to accomplish this by using absolute addressing for fields of a record:

```pascal
type
  FLAG_1_T = ( F1_V1, F1_V2, F1_V3 );
  FLAG_2_T = ( F1_V1, F1_V2        );

type
  DATA_ITEM_T = record
    id     : BYTE_T;
    value  : INT32_T;
    flag_1 : FLAG_1_T;
    flag_2 : FLAG_2_T absolute flag_1;
  end;
```

But this fails to compile with syntax error `E2029 ';' expected but identifier 'absolute' found`.

If I bring those flag declarations outside of the record type definition (but at the same scope as the record type def), it compiles fine:

*note that this is useless for what I'm trying to accomplish*

```pascal
type
  FLAG_1_T = ( F1_V1, F1_V2, F1_V3 );
  FLAG_2_T = ( F1_V1, F1_V2        );

type
  DATA_ITEM_T = record
    id     : BYTE_T;
    value  : INT32_T;
  end;

var
  flag_1 : FLAG_1_T;
  flag_2 : FLAG_2_T absolute flag_1;
```

So why can't I do this within a record? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate a C union to Delphi using a record type with a [variant part](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records):

```
type
  FLAG_T = record
    case Boolean of
      False: (flag_1: FLAG_1_T);
      True: (flag_2: FLAG_2_T);
  end;
```

Comment: Is there not any extra space required for that boolean ..thing in the record? I mean, will `FLAG_T` be the *exact* same size as the largest of `FLAG_1_T` and `FLAG_2_T`?

Comment: Extra space will be reserved only if you declare it with a field tag, like `case B: Boolean of`... This is explained in the linked documentation, too: "The tag, if there is one, functions as an extra field..." Without the tag, yes, `FLAG_T` will be the exact same size as the largest of `FLAG_1_T` and `FLAG_2_T`.

Comment: FWIW, as soon as you have a third member, you have to switch to a different ordinal type. So I prefer to be consistent across a code base and use `Integer` as the ordinal type for all my variant records.

Comment: Looks great, thanks - btw what did they do with that `end` brace for the case statement?!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan FWIW I prefer not to be consistent - on purpose - and always use the smallest possible ordinal type, switching to a different one only when required. The difference is only cosmetic, though.

Comment: @ardnew The `end` which would match the `case` is omitted because there can only be one variant part in a record and it has to be the last one.

Comment: Has to be the last one? Well this doesn't solve the problem then. The data I'm dealing with has quite a few fields after this flag field

Comment: You can put those additional fields into one of the variants.

Comment: @TOndrej No you can't. That can screw up the alignment. Rudy's otherwise excellent article on the topic of unions makes this same mistake.

Comment: @ardnew It does solve your problem. You make a separate type to represent the union and include that in your outer record.

Comment: @TOndrej Why do you prefer to use a small type? It's not consuming space. Do you make an enumerated type for each different union where the count is >2

Comment: So you use `Boolean` when there are 2, and a bespoke enum when there are more? That seems perverse. Why not use a bespoke enum always.

Comment: @TOndrej In general, the only way to get the alignment right is to make the union a standalone variant record. It's very easy to construct a C structure that can only be represented that way.

Comment: Well, I guess you have the kind of mind that transforms `False` and `True` into enumerated type names depending on the context. I posit that it is just habit that has you using `Boolean`. Enums are a good option, but then switching from enums to `Boolean` when you go from 3 to 2, well, that cannot have been an explicitly considered decision. Has to be habit.

Comment: The standalone variant record types more closely resembles a union in that outermost record anyway, thanks again

Comment: A lot of people will advise you to cram the union into the outer record as the final variant part. Even if that means cheating and stuffing members that follow the union into the end of one of the variant record cases. I suspect that I am in a minority in advising against that. However, my advise is the only advise that allows you to get the alignment and layout correct in general. FWIW, you don't actually need to declare a separate type for the union, you can declare inline records directly. I'll post a short example in a moment.

Comment: `type
  TMyRec = record
    i: Integer;
    union: record
      case Integer of
      0: (d: Double);
      1: (s: Single);
    end;
    b: Boolean;
  end;`  But you'll need to forgive the formatting because that's a mess in comments!!!  Paste it into Delphi and hit CTRL+D!

Comment: @David, huh, perverse is making a *reserve* for up to 2147483647 variants :-) Having even close to `Byte` high bounds of variants would be perversion.

Comment: @TLama What exactly is being reserved? I cannot see any reservation at all. I'm good with enums, they are fine. I also think that integers are fine because the values are not relevant, at least when the tag has no field. They can be understood as meaningless values.

Comment: @David, you said that you use `Integer` as the ordinal type for all your variant records and I meant that you are making a *reserve* for having `Low(Integer)..High(Integer)` number of possible variants (I did not consider whole range in my last comment). I know they are irrelevant without a field, but having `Byte` is enough in real. Who would ever define more than 255 variants in a record ?

Comment: @TLama `Byte` would be fine too. But `Integer` is the native integer type and almost all integer variables that I ever declare are of type `Integer`. So that feels natural to me. `Byte` is fine too I agree. What feels weird to me is `Boolean` with those wacky names for the branches of the union.

Comment: FWIW I defined new enum types for the cases in each of the unions I converted to variant records. Just seems clearer that way